# How to check if a timeslot lies between two other timeslots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have 3 time stamps

StartTime: 22:30:00

EndTime: 05:00:00

CurrentTime: 03:00:00

Now if the current time lies between StartTime and EndTime, then I want to print the "CurrentTime". So in the above example since CurrentTime is between 22:30:00 and 05:00:00, hence I wish to print it.

So I used the following code

```
const StartTime = new Date("2019-02-22T23:00");
const EndTime = new Date("2019-02-23T05:00");
const CurrentTime = new Date("2022-02-23T03:00");

const StartTimeHours = StartTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
const EndTimeHours = EndTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
const CurrentHours = CurrentTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false});

if (StartTimeHours < CurrentHours && CurrentHours < EndTimeHours)
{
    console.log("Current Time",CurrentHours);
}
```

However, since 05:00:00 is less than 22:30:00, hence it is not printing the output. So how do I make it check that the EndTime is between the two time slots

Comment: Impossible with pure timestamps, 03:00 is always between 22:30 and 05:00. You've to make an assumption of the same day or define dates.

Answer (score 0):

There were some minor issues in your code, 
but you can try checking on the full date-time values, like so:

```js
const StartTime = new Date("2022-02-22T23:00");
const EndTime = new Date("2022-02-23T05:00");
const CurrentTime = new Date("2022-02-23T03:00");

const StartTimeHours = StartTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
const EndTimeHours = EndTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
const CurrentHours = CurrentTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false});

if (StartTime < CurrentTime && CurrentTime < EndTime)
{
    console.log("Current Time",CurrentHours);
}
```

Comment: Comparing the full date is not logically correct for this data, since the starttime and endtime could be of any month/year/day, only time part is relevant @niccord

Comment: the only way to make 03:00 greater than 22:30 is by expressing this difference using the date part: you have to find a way to put that in your code somehow